# Verifying a release builds

Tags: iphone, shared-libraries, itunes, xcodebuild

My projects reference static DLLs I've created.  These projects are setup to make sure a corresponding build phase occurs.  Meaning, if I build in simulator/debug, the static library will have an up to date simulator/debug build.  I can verify my app works fine except for device/release.  Is there a way to verify device/release?  It's sort of like throwing it over the wall to Apple without any verification.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is?

Comment: I think the general question is: Can you test whether a release build works before sending it off and waiting a week to find out it doesn't actually run?  Or is there any way to perform QA on a build signed by the app store certificate.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use the Release configuration to build with your development profile, and create a new Distribute configuration. The new configuration should be identical to the Release configuration in all ways except that it uses your distribution certs for signing rather than your development certs.

To do this, just go into your project settings, go to the Configurations tab, and duplicate the Release configuration, then rename the duplicate to Distribute. Then go to the Build tab, select the Distribute configuration from the drop down, and change the Code Signing Identity to use your distribution certificate.

Now you are ensured that the output of the two configurations is the same except for the code signing step. If you change build settings in the future, just delete and recreate the Distribute profile to ensure all the settings are the same.